# How to url rewrite for multi-lang Joomla site (add fake sub directory in url)

Tags: joomla, url-rewriting, subdirectory

How to url rewrite for multi-lang Joomla site:

Now is:
Enter:
www.example.com/

Redirect to English site:

www.example.com/en/

====================================================

What I want to do is:

Enter:
www.example.com/hk/en/ (Not redirect to www.example.com/en/hk/en/ which is wrong)

And reading this:
www.example.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

There is a default Joomla plugin called **Language Filter** which should take care of this.

If you haven't already enabled it, then I would suggest you do via the Plugin Manager in the Joomla Backend and adjust the parameters accordingly to whatever suits you.